# What is wrong with this? Getting same error in eclipse

Tags: java

Hey i am getting errors all over the place for the same 2 words. Im not sure what i am doing wrong but i hope you guys can find the error. Basically i am terrible at writing java, but i still wanted to make a program so i found a java program that is basically what i needed and now i am editing it to my specifications in Eclipse.

ERROR: has two "**" on each side, ERROR message for all of them "Duplicate local variable "

```
public String sentenceLyrics()
  {
    ArrayList<String> toBeUsed = new ArrayList();
    for (int a = 0; a < this.slyrics.length; a++) {
      if (this.blyrics[a]) {
        toBeUsed.add(this.slyrics[a]);
      }
    }
    int numofdouble;
    int numofsingle;
    int **numofdouble**; 
    if (toBeUsed.size() == 1)
    {
      int **numofsingle** = 1;
      numofdouble = 0;
    }
    else if (toBeUsed.size() > 1)
    {
      int **numofdouble** = rand.nextInt(toBeUsed.size() / 2);
      int **numofsingle** = toBeUsed.size() - numofdouble * 2;
      System.out.println(numofdouble + " " + numofsingle);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have variables with the same name, just like the error message says.

While it's impossible to know what your *intent* is, did you just want to declare them once and use them throughout the rest of your code? If so, remove the *declarations* after the first ones, e.g., remove the leading `int` types, and simply set their values.

Answer (score 0):

For the first set of `**`, there's not really much to say except that you're declaring the variable again. The fix there would be to remove that line.

For the other three errors, the problem is that when you say [type] [variable name], Java thinks that you're declaring a new variable, when it seems that all you want to do is assign a new value to an existing variable. To fix this, simply remove the `int` labels, and the errors should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the same variable name more than twice. In Java if you write this:

```
int numofsingle
```

then you are declaring that variable. You assign a value to the variable by doing the following:

```
numofsingle = 1
```

Note the lack of `int` at the start.

What you are doing is declaring a variable and assigning a value on the same line of code multi times to the same named variable. Just drop the `int` from the lines that you have marked with **

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is want you wanted to do:

```
public String sentenceLyrics() {
    ArrayList<String> toBeUsed = new ArrayList();
    for (int a = 0; a < this.slyrics.length; a++) {
      if (this.blyrics[a]) {
        toBeUsed.add(this.slyrics[a]);
      }
    }
    int numofdouble = 0;
    int numofsingle = 0;
    if (toBeUsed.size() == 1)
    {
      numofsingle = 1;
      numofdouble = 0;
    }
    else if (toBeUsed.size() > 1)
    {
      numofdouble = rand.nextInt(toBeUsed.size() / 2);
      numofsingle = toBeUsed.size() - numofdouble * 2;
    }
    System.out.println(numofdouble + " " + numofsingle);
}
```

Removed variable duplication, added some curly braces, and added some variable initialization.